# JavaScript の配列で `[要素,...][要素] || 要素` の動作がわからない

Tags: javascript

fizzBuzz関数中、ライン23の`||`の前後の動作を教えて頂きたいです。
`[i % 15] || i`の部分です。

*コンソールの結果は、コメントしてあるfizzBuzz関数と同じになりました。

```
function start(x) {
    fizzBuzz(x);
}

// function fizzBuzz(x) { // REG!
//     var i = 0;
//     for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
//         if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
//             console.log("fizzbuzz");
//         } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
//             console.log("fizz");
//         } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
//             console.log("buzz");
//         } else {
//             console.log(i);
//         }
//     }
// }

function fizzBuzz(max) {
    var F = 'Fizz', B = 'Buzz';
    for (var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        console.log([F+B,0,0,F,0,B,F,0,0,F,B,0,F,0,0][i % 15] || i);
    }
}
```

Comment: 基本的にコードは画像ではなくテキストで貼り付けてもらえませんか？スマホなど環境によっては小さく読みづらいですし、テキストなら回答で引用する時にコピペすることができます。一部を強調したいとしても「`[i%15]||i`の部分」と言葉で説明すれば十分かと。

Comment: @unarist それは申し訳ありません。私自身、モバイルの方から投稿し、画像のほうが(通信量は多いですが)拡大でき見やすいと思い画像を使用させてもらっていました。貴重なご意見ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

まず`[F+B,0,0,F,0,B,F,0,0,F,B,0,F,0,0]`はFizzBuzzの0から14に対する結果を収めた配列です。
次にこの配列から`i % 15`番目の要素(`value`)を取り出しています。
最後に`|| i`ですが、JavaScriptの`||`演算子は左辺が`true`と見なせる場合は左辺の値を、そうでなければ右辺の値を返す操作ですので`0 || i`は`i`になります。
ですので23行の内容は冗長に書くと以下のような処理になります。

```
var array = [F+B,0,0,F,0,B,F,0,0,F,B,0,F,0,0];
var value = array[i % 15];
if (value !== 0) {
    console.log(value);
} else {
    console.log(i);
}
```